# DocuSign custom tags - CustomTabRequired property

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign's SOAP based API calls to create envelope(s) into the selected DocuSign account. While adding custom tags, if I do not require recipient to enter the information in the custom tag, I setup the custom tag property "CustomTabRequired" to false. If I require recipient to enter the information in the custom tag, I set the the custom tag property 
"CustomTabRequired" to true and "CustomTabRequiredSpecified" to true.

When an envelope gets created and if I haven't setup the custom tag required property to true, it still forces recipient to fill in the information in order to complete the signing process.
Is there anything that I need to setup other than these two properties?
I have observed this behavior for my DocuSign demo account as well as live account.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

We've connected outside of Stack Overflow and found that some properties are being dropped from your request, but for the benefit of the community-

When using the DocuSign SOAP API and creating a custom tab, you just need to make sure the `CustomTabRequired` property is set to `true`.  For instance, in PHP you could create the tab like this:

```
//+++ Add Custom Tab +++
$tab = new Tab();
$tab->DocumentID = "1";
$tab->RecipientID = "1";
$tab->PageNumber = "1";
$tab->Type = TabTypeCode::Custom;
$tab->Name = "CustomTextTag1";
$tab->TabLabel = "CustomTextTag1";
$tab->CustomTabType = CustomTabType::Text;
$tab->CustomTabRequired = false;
$tab->XPosition = "100";
$tab->YPosition = "100";
```

The important bit that makes the tab optional as you are trying to accomplish is this:

```
$tab->CustomTabRequired = false;
```

As long as that property is present in your request it will make the tab in question optional.  Please note that if using DocuSign's REST API the corresponding JSON property is simply labeled as `required`.

Comment: We found/resolved the issue. While setting up the custom tag property CustomTabRequired=false, we needed to explicitly set the property CustomTabRequiredSpecified=true. It looks like SOAP based API calls require us to set the specified properties as well for each tag property. When we ignore those specified properties, the tag properties are not being set correctly. Thank you so much for your help.